# Get Data from foreign key in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have created two tables in Sqlite one have the **main experience data** and other have the **details of the data** as

```
class experience(models.Model):
  e_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  e_post = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  e_startdate = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  e_enddate = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.e_name

class experiencedetail(models.Model):
  e_name = models.ForeignKey(experience,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  e_detail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

i am trying to shoe the details as
[shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKDgW.png)

my Html code is

```
    {% for exp in experience %}
    <div id="{{exp.e_name}}" class="tabcontent">
            <h2 class="hf">{{exp.e_post}} @ <span>{{ exp.e_name }}</span></h2>
            <p>{{exp.e_startdate}} - {{exp.e_enddate}}- {{exp.id}}</p>
            <div class="exp-description">
                <h4>
                    <ul style="list-style: square;">
                        {% for expd in exp_detail %}
                            {% if 'expd.e_name' == 'exp.e_name' %}
                                <li>{{ expd.e_detail }}</li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

but this expd.details does not show any data. The data is present in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `exp_detail` does not exists. You access the reversed `ForeignKey` manager with:

```
{% for expd in exp.experiencedetail_set.all %}
    <li>{{ expd.e_detail }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The name of the reversed manager is the value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). If you do not specify this parameter in your `ForeignKey`, it will use `modelname_set`.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`experiencedetail`</s> to `ExperienceDetail`.